# Can't record fields into database (php, SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to take a form that a user inputs from an HTML site and send the information to a SQL database. I am able to print out the variables after submission, so I know at the very least the variables are set properly. So I have to assume my code to send the content to the database is at fault here.

Here's the code:

```
//Taking variables from HTML input
if (isset($_POST['group'])) {
    $group = $_POST['group'];
} else {
    echo $error;  return;
}
if (isset($_POST['game'])) {
    $game = $_POST['game'];
} else {
    echo $error;  return;
}
if (isset($_POST['platform'])) {
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];
} else {
    echo $error;  return;
}
if (isset($_POST['player'])) {
    $player = $_POST['player'];
} else {
    echo $error;  return;
}
if (isset($_POST['play'])) {
    $play = $_POST['play'];
} else {
    echo $error;  return;
}
if (isset($_POST['timezone'])) {
    $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];
} else {
    echo $error;  return;
}
$error = 0;
//Retrieving Databse
try {
    //userID and password is defined, just hiding it here
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userID", "userID", "password");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die("<p>($e->getMessage())</p></body></html>)");
}
//Inputting content into MySQL
$command = "INSERT INTO teams ( group, game, platform, player, play, timezone ) 
            VALUES ( '$group','$game','$platform','$player','$play','$timezone')";
$stmt = $dbh -> prepare($command);
if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
    $error = "<b>ERROR:</b> Could not record fields";  echo $error;  return;
}
```

I'm not really sure where I've gone wrong, could be possible it's the tiniest thing or just something I've overlooked.

Thanks in advance for any help, guys!

Comment: Be careful with POST values. You're not validating them!

Comment: Guess what... `group`... is a reserved word. Use backticks ;) or use another word for it.

Comment: Lovely SQL injection attack vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: The use of PDO is not a safeguard against SQL injection; not on its own that is. Use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: You're using PDO and yet you're not structuring your queries so as to avoid [SQL injections](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png). You might as well be using mysql_* functions.

Comment: You're also not checking for errors. add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, which would've signaled an error.

Comment: This isn't for anything important, it's just a college assignment.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I've got things working now.

Comment: @CSRadical college assignments are very important. you should go above and beyond the professors expectations, on every single assignment. Come graduation time, you will be the best programmer in your class because you put in all the work. Then you can ask your professor for a job reference even. When you put the work in, your professors will put their neck out for you as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it for my Assignment:
Connecting to MySQL (notice that I dont have any *mysql:host=*):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "pass", "database_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
```

Then in your code, when initializing variabels from POST, escape the strings. This will give you some protection against SQL-Injections:

```
$Name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["txtName"]);
$Street = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["txtStreet"]);
$City = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["txtCity"]);
```

Now, prepare a SQL code to insert your params:

```
$input = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO customer (MembershipID, Name, Street, City, PostCode, Email, Password, DateJoin, Salt) 
    VALUES ('". $MembershipID."','".$Name."','".$Street."','". $City."','". $PostCode."','". $Email."','". $Password."','". $DateJoined."','". $Salt."')");
```

I hope it helps, Good Luck.

Comment: _... escape the strings. This will give you some protection against SQL-Injections._ No it won't, escaping does not prevent injection.